# Retrofit: read from cache on connection timeout

Tags: android, http, caching, retrofit, okhttp

Is there a way to read from cache if a connection timeout occurs?

**All the cache is working**, but it only works if there's no internet.

I already know how to check the timeout exception:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    if(t instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
        // I want to load from cache here.
    }
}
```